# Angular.js returns me the error $parse lexerr

Tags: angularjs

Hello guys I am new with Angular.js and I am studying on Linkedin Learning, I am trying to develop a form with Angular.
Everything worked fine but when I started to add the page app.js, I receive an error Error: **[$parse:lexerr:**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('RegistrationController' , ['$scope',
       function($scope) {

       $scope.register = function () {

           $scope.message = "Benvenuto " + $scope.user.firstname;

       };

    }]);
```

The html code is the following but I think I have done everything correctly:

```
...

   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="page">
         <!-- only this section is controlled by AngularJS -->
         <section class="card register" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="RegistrationController">
            <form name="myform" ng-submit="register()" novalidate>
               <div class="textintro">
                  <h1>Form Validation</h1>
                  <p>Compila il seguente form</p>
                  <p ng-show="message">{{ message }}</p>
               </div>
               <!-- attributi Angular per i campi: ng-required, ng-minlength, ng-maxlength ed ng-pattern (pattern validation) -->
               <fieldset>
                  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Nome" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-required="true" />
                  <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.firstname.$invalid && myform.firstname.$touched">Devi inserire il tuo nome</p>
                  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Cognome" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-required="true"/>
                  <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.lastname.$invalid && myform.lastname.$touched">Devi inserire il tuo cognome</p>
                  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" />
                  <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.lastname.$invalid && myform.lastname.$touched">Devi inserire una email valida</p>
                  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="6" />
                  <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.password.$invalid && myform.password.$touched">La password deve avere almeno 6 caratteri</p>

               </fieldset>
               <button type="submit" class="btn">Invia</button>
            </form>
         </section>
      </div>
 ....
```

Thank you for everyone who will help me to find the error and if can explain me what this error means.

Comment: Move `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` to just before the end of the `body` tag

Comment: What is the full error? **[$parse:lexerr:** is just the start of the error

Comment: @AlonEitan full error:
 angular.js:15570 Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%207-7%20%5B%C3%82%5D&p2=message%C3%82
    at angular.js:99
    at Nb.throwError (angular.js:15749)
    at Nb.lex (angular.js:15672)
    at q.ast (angular.js:15873)
    at Mb.getAst (angular.js:17237)
    at Mb.parse (angular.js:17220)
    at f (angular.js:17378)
    at angular.js:13939
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at h (angular.js:13939)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava tried but still I receive same error :(

Comment: @Emilio Try changing all the `ng-minlength` instances into `minlength` (without the `ng-`), same goes for `ng-required`

Comment: Also, the error say something about this line: `<p ng-show="message">{{ message }}</p>` try removing it just to see if the error goes away

Comment: Your code (at least the one provided here) works without any error https://jsfiddle.net/ao2vt7hg/ Please provide a JSFiddle to reproduce the error or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @AlonEitan doing as you have suggested to me helped me to let the code working fine. Answer my question so that I can "Approve" your answer